# How to read a line in a file and write this line in a other file

Tags: jython

I have got this script in Jython.

I try to open a specific file, read it, reach a specific line and write this line in an other file.

```
infile = open(ttool.getVariable('CRE_PEC_var'), 'r');
outfile = open(ttool.getVariable('CRE_PEC_var_out'), 'w');
    for line in infile: 
        if "PCCATE" in line:
            outfile.write(line);
outfile.close();
infile.close();
```

But when I launch the script, I get this error :

```
ERROR Error executing 'Script Jython [Supression de la deuxième ligne de CR...]' : *** PySyntaxError : null:
SyntaxError: ("mismatched input '' expecting EOF", ('', 5, 1, '\tfor line in infile: \n'))
```

How can I fix this?

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

May be Indentation problem try the below one

```
infile = open(ttool.getVariable('CRE_PEC_var'), 'r');
outfile = open(ttool.getVariable('CRE_PEC_var_out'), 'w');
for line in infile: 
  if "PCCATE" in line:
    outfile.write(line);
outfile.close();
infile.close();
```